# Page request and memory optimization in PHP/APACHE

Tags: php, web-services, apache, http, micro-optimization

Let's say in my website I have user & admin `.php` pages. the user page accommodates requests made by users, which may be 5000 pageviews a day, but my admin page gets only `100` page views (from me) per day.

Now, I was thinking being able to access my admin control panel from the index page, but I am not sure if my 100+ requests will interfere with the performance of the site and affect the user's experience.

I am thinking Apache does not care if 5500 users accessed the same index page, instead of allocating and distributing the requests based on the importance of the page.

I just don't know which one is the recommended method for micro-optimization.

Comment: Are you asking if serving the same `index.php` file to both admin and normal site users will affect performance compared to naming the files differently e.g. `admin.php` and `index.php`?

Comment: Micro-optimization it is! 5500 pageviews a day are nothing for PHP/Apache!

Comment: @thatidiotguy yes. I want to know if my 100 visits won't have even the slights effect on the 5000 users accessing the site as I do with `index.php`

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I know that, but it is more like trying to understand how HTTP/Servers work. that is why I am asking this question

Comment: If you really feel the need to optimise the pages in your site i would suggest looking at caching. You can do this for various different things but you could look at DB query caching, HTTP caching and Etags. But for 5000 views it is not really a lot!

Comment: @MarcelKorpel lets look at it this way. Are you saying a weak server serving `a.php` page to a million users is identical to a weak server serving 10 different pages to 100,000 users?

Comment: You'll have a *little* extra overhead, because the page is not in the cache of the server, but that's all. And why a *weak* server? What did you do wrong elsewhere (configuration and the like) that your server is weak?

Comment: No weak server. I just gave you an example to better illustrate the example.

Comment: For boost your website use `memcached + php_memcache + disable debug and pure errors` and revalidate your code for fix queries (recursive) and duplicate codes. Anyway, 5000 visit is nothing to apache, maybye 5000 per second in certain day hour. (Sorry for my english).